# How to display website in cordova?

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-cordova, phonegap, apache-cordova

i'm just wanted to know how to simply display my website into a crossplatform mobile app using cordova? What I need to change into index.html or config.xml?

Comment: When you ask question you have to be more specific, first you need to try to solve it, if not put question here with what you tried.... then you will get good clear answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Cordova plugin InAppBrowser https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/

Answer (score 0):

No need to change, if you just want your cordova project would run on web as well then use below command :

```
cordova platform add browser
```

This works for me.